# How to use wp_insert_user on Wordpress Multisite?

Tags: php, multisite

I previously had a WordpressMU install, but this is deprecated and I'm trying to find my way around multisite.

I need to programatically create a new user account for a particular site. [wp_insert_user](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user) looks like it does everything except say which site the user is *for* (perhaps it takes this from the domain the request was sent to?).

It's important that the created user is a member on one blog (site), but not the other(s).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the **add_user_to_blog** function after creating the user.

```
$userid = 1;
$blogid = 5;
$role = 'administrator';
add_user_to_blog( $blogid, $userid, $role );
```

Comment: Hmm. creating the user already adds the user to the blog on the URL used to create the user.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have Wordpress Multisite, with sites: `example.com`, `foo.example.com` and `bar.example.co`m and you want to add a new user to `foo.example.com`, then create a script and execute that script via a URL containing `foo.example.com/path/to/your/script.ph`.

Wordpress detects the URL, maps it to a blog and assigns users created by `wp_insert_user()` to that blog, and not to the other blogs.

See the answer by Chittaranjan if you then want to add the user to a other blogs/sites, too.